# VBA Combobox not displaying all columns

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a user form with a combobox with items populated like this:

```
For Each thing in things
    With Me.Combobox1
        .AddItem
        .List(i, 0) = thing.thing1
        .List(i, 1) = thing.thing2
        ...
        .List(i, 4) = thing.thing5
    End with
Next thing
```

In the properties of the combobox I have `BoundColumn = 3` and `ColumnCount = 5` and I have set list width as high as 700, and there is plenty of blank space to display my other values, but I can never get more than the first three columns to display.

`ColumnWidths` does not appear to be working properly for me either.  I have tried to set the width of the first column to 1, a hack to get a particular value to populate the .text property and display in the text box portion of the control, and I've set the second column, a single character flag to 15 which seems to work well, but any further column widths seem to be ignored completely.

I've been cruising through the documentation but I can't find anything that addresses this issue.